# SSMS Crashes when attempting to restore DB from Azure URL

Tags: sql-server, restore, ssms, azure-blob-storage

I'd previously been using the April 2016 version of SQL Server Management Studio with no issues, but have run into problems since updating to the GA June 2016 version of SSMS.  When I try to restore a DB from Azure blob storage, SSMS immediately crashes.  I'm choosing Restore Database > Device > clicking the browse (3 dots) button > changing backup media type to "URL" > clicking the "Add" button.  SSMS crashes immediately upon selecting the "Add button."
I've tried going back to the April 2016 version, removing all versions of SSMS, repairing SQL 2014, reapplying SP1 and CU6, and reinstalling the new June SSMS.
I'm wondering if it has something to do with the saved Azure credentials that SSMS was using to access the blob storage.  How do I remove those credentials to see if that's the case? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Event viewer details:

```
Application: Ssms.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Exception
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RegSvrEnum.DataProtection.UnprotectData(Byte[], Int32)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RegSvrEnum.DataProtection.UnprotectData(System.String)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.RegSvrEnum.UIConnectionInfo.get_Password()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.AzureConnectToStorageDialog.HasAccountInformation(System.Object, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.AzureConnectToStorageDialog.set_DataSource(Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.AzureConnectToStorageViewData)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.AzureConnectToStorageDialog.AzureConnectToStorageDialog_Load(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(System.EventArgs)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control+ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(System.Windows.Forms.Message ByRef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr, Int32, IntPtr, IntPtr)
```

More details:

```
Faulting application name: Ssms.exe, version: 2015.130.15000.23, time stamp: 0x573fd920
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.18264, time stamp: 0x56e1b34d
Exception code: 0xe0434352
Fault offset: 0x00015b68
Faulting process id: 0x2900
Faulting application start time: 0x01d1bf54f078f2e5
Faulting application path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\130\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\Ssms.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 3c1dd04f-2b48-11e6-80c7-00155d745d0a
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```